# Error Installing Matlab

Tags: software-installation

When I install Matlab I get this error:

```
fawaz@fawaz-Lenovo-B590~$ sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```